# PHP script using random returns the same output every time

Tags: php, random

I have a PHP script that is supposed to create a MySQL table and fill it with some data.

The column question should be filled with random numbers between 1 and $AutoInc which I define earlier in the code.
For some reason I always end up with the same questions:

[image: Question is always 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]

I tried to sleep between the numbers and used rand() and random_int() instead of mt_rand() none of that worked.

PS: I know that $statement3 is terribly coded. For some reason I couldn't get it to work using Questionmarks and an array. I'll change that later so just ignore it.

```
$usedQuestionsArray = array();
$AutoInc = 12;
for ($x = 0; $x <= 11; $x++) {
    $randomNum = mt_rand(1, $AutoInc);
    while(in_array($randomNum, $usedQuestionsArray)){
        $randomNum = mt_rand(1, $AutoInc);
    }
    array_push($usedQuestionsArray, $randomNum);
    $statement3 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO match" . $ID ." (Question, P" . 
$Player1 . ",P" . $Player2 . ") VALUES (" . $randomNum . ",0,0);");
    $statement3 = $statement3->execute();
}
```

Comment: What's the value of $AutoInc  ?  Just print it out to be sure it got picked up ...

Comment: Does not matter . Let it be 12

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Plugging in values that I've made up, it seems to work.  But I don't know if that represents what you're actually doing.  [See here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34f7e4dca8eba0cf6cce5c1c601a310d3dbf84ff).  Protip: When you're creating a query via variable interpolation, echo out the generated query and see if it's actually what you expect it to be.

Comment: it's 12 otherwise there wouldn't be 12 rows since Question is PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Problem is in mysql .  I think you set it auto increment (Question) . Did you ?

Comment: looks this https://3v4l.org/H9KbQ

Comment: Sadly no Question is set to be PRIMARY KEY, but not to do auto increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake:
Question is PRIMARY_KEY Therefore the Table is sorted accordingly.
I set Question to UNIQUE now its working.